# String variable as pattern in Regex() constructor

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015

I can't use pattern in string variable because regex never match.

Let me describe what I want to achieve. I have a service which returns string pattern for password. Let's say the current pattern is:

```
\\b(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}\\b
```

Which means that password need to contains at least 6 characters, one digit and one capital letter. I test it by:

```
string passwordPattern = "\\b(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}\\b";
var rgxPasswordPattern = new Regex(passwordPattern);
var result = rgxPasswordPattern.IsMatch("Password1");

if(result)
    Console.Write("Password match!");
else
    Console.Write("Password doesn't match!");
```

It works, you can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FNzZjh

The problem occur when I use above code in my environment. The only difference is the way how I get my password pattern:

```
string passwordPattern = _signInService.GetPasswordPattern();
```

I noticed that `passwordPattern` contains pattern wraped with quoted marks:
[image]

This causes the `rgxPasswordPattern` contains quoted marks too:
[image]

So, I've removed quoted marks from pattern by `passwordPattern.Substring(1, passwordPattern.Length - 2)`:

[image]

And checked `rgxPasswordPattern` variable:
[image]

Yup, there is no additional quoted marks. But password still not match with pattern!
[image]

How can it be possible? I don't have any idea what else can I do. Pattern is fine and works in *dotnetfiddle.net* but not in my environment.

I will appreciate every advice.

Comment: Yes, I typed it directly into `IsMatch()` method (you can see that on the last picture in my question).

Comment: No, it won't work, I've described this scenarion on the top of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
string passwordPattern = "\\b(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}\\b";
```

in C# means `passwordPattern` actually contains the following string

```
\b(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,}\b //notice backslahes count
```

When you are defining string in C# backslash escapes the following character. So if you want to add `\` character to string you have to put double backslash there `\\`. So the problem with your service is that it is returning extra backslashes in the pattern.

Comment: OMG, you are right, the problem was double backslash. Thanks for help, you saved my day :)